# WinAppDriver tests fail when screen is locked

Tags: c#, uwp, appium, coded-ui-tests, winappdriver

I am using winAppDriver to test UWP app but tests fail when screen is locked as it's not able to find the element and works ok when screen is not locked. Any solution to run winAppTest even screen is locked? I am worried about how I am gonna with TFS :(. Please advice.

Regards,
Ref

Comment: you are using Android or ios?

Comment: it's a desktop app and I have found there is no way I can by pass screen locking so I have planned to run in TFS or locally by putting power point presentation running in the background so screen doesnt get locked.

Comment: Which OS you have. I solved this issue on Windows.

Comment: I am using windows 10 - enterprise 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

Unlocking the machine is mandatory, the UI testing frameworks like WinAppDriver(and it's predecessor CodedUI) need an active UI session in order to automate the UI.

The requirement is document on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-set-up-your-test-agent-to-run-tests-that-interact-with-the-desktop?view=vs-2019) link. 
I'm sharing the screenshot below FYI. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: you are right. I have found this fact as well and planned to run my tests in TFS  or locally by putting power point presentation running in the background so screen doesnt get locked.

Comment: The TFS builds have a default timeout of 30 minutes, the build will fail by default when time goes beyond that. If you found the answer to be useful please click the up arrow. :)